# Send file path from flask to Ajax

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I'm trying to send a file path to my Ajax script which reads file contents and displays it on the page

```
@app.route('/main', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    filename = '/static/js/'+current_user.username+'log.txt'
    return render_template('main.html',name=current_user.username,data=filename)
```

js script

```
var checkInterval = 1; //seconds
var fileServer = '{{ data }}';
var lastData;

function checkFile() {
    $.get(fileServer, function (data) {

        if (lastData !== data) {
            $( "#target" ).val( data );
            $( "#target" ).animate({
                scrollTop: $( "#target" )[0].scrollHeight - $( "#target" ).height()
            }, 'slow');
            lastData = data;
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(checkFile, 1000 * checkInterval);
});
```

I tried different ways to do this, changed fileServer to 'data.filename'/{{ data| json }} etc but got no luck.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the entire url generated with `url_for` as a parameter it should work.

```
@app.route('/main', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    filename = url_for('static', filename=f'js/{current_user.username}log.txt')
    return render_template('main.html', name=current_user.username, data=filename)
```

As a supplement, I also specify that the request should not be stored in the cache.

```
const checkInterval = 1;
const fileServer = "{{ data }}";
let lastData;

function checkFile() {
  $.get({ url: fileServer, cache: false }, function(data) {
    if (lastData !== data) {
      $("#target").val(data);
      $("#target").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#target")[0].scrollHeight - $("#target").height()
      }, "slow");
      lastData = data;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(checkFile, 1000 * checkInterval);
});
```

I used jquery version 3 for testing.

Comment: does not work for me. got this in console `
jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 GET http://127.0.0.1:5002/%7B%7B%20data%20%7D%7D 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Comment: @Goroshek  It seems as if jinja does not pass the variable or does not convert the ```{{data}}``` statement. I can't explain myself at the moment.

Comment: @Goroshek It works for me now with ```f'/static/js/{current_user.username}log.txt'``` and without ```url_for```. But your current problem is different.

Comment: @Goroshek Sorry, I cannot reproduce the error and do not know why it occurs.

Comment: @Goroshek   Sorry, I didn't think that you could have split the code into several files. 
The statement ```{{data}}``` only works within the jinja2 template, 
not within an external javascript file. Passing the url as an argument is one solution.

Comment: yes, I can't pass Jinja vars to external files. That was a problem. Thanks!

Comment: wht if my file to send is not in static. It is in some another folder. So in that case, I can not create a folder. what will be the solution for such case?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani In this case you are referencing a [custom route](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) that takes the file path as a parameter and sends the file from the directory using [`send_from_directory`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory).